# If my team-mate absorbs a creature we have been fighting, will the rest of the party still gain EXP?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points, gmpc

My DM is playing a DMPC along with our party, as well as the standard DM role.

During an encounter, his PC absorbed a gelatinous cube, and is saying that because it was not a true kill, the rest of the party doesn't gain experience, even though we did damage the cube.

Is this in line with the rules, or are we getting screwed by our DM?

Comment: How did he "absorb" the gelatinous cube? Is this an ability his character has, or what?

Comment: In soviet Russia, gelatinous cube absorbs- Oh, wait. Hmm.

Comment: Also, did *his* character gain EXP?

Comment: How far into the encounter did this happen?  Was it almost immediate, and thus the NPC essentially negated the whole encounter, or did this happen after your party had already spent several rounds learning that you don't attack it with blunt weapons?

Comment: @Taegost From the question: "…even though we did damage the cube." So, not immediate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - yes, that's why I said "almost immediate".  They could have dealt damage to the cube in the first round, or by other means prior to combat beginning.  The point I'm trying to get at is the amount of effort they put forth prior to the deus ex machina.  If they only hit it for 10hp or setting fire to a barn from teh outside, that's different than getting it down to 50%

Comment: @Taegost I don't believe it is actually a relevant difference to XP awards.

Comment: I am still waiting for answer to @Miniman's question :D

Comment: Was the dmpc a cube as well? or was he a human and ate the cube? how did it work??

Answer (score 33):

DMG p. 260

> When adventurers **defeat** one or more
>   monsters-typically by killing, routing, or capturing them-they divide the total XP value of the monsters
>   evenly among themselves. If the party received
>   **substantial assistance** **from** one or more **NPCs**, **count
>   those NPCs as party members** when dividing up the
>   XP. (Because the NPCs made the fight easier, individual
>   characters receive fewer XP.)

On the face of it, it appears the "adventurers defeat[ed] one or more
monsters". Also, on the face of it the NPC gave "substantial assistance". Therefore according to RAW the XP should be divided the number of PCs + NPCs that gave "substantial assistance" (1)  and everyone should get that amount.

With reference to your question:

1. This is not in line with the rules
2. You are getting screwed by your DM. I use the term non-pejoratively and do not suggest that this "screwing" involves malice or vindictiveness, it is entirely possible it is from ignorance.

I defer to [How should I restrain myself when both playing a character and DMing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/how-should-i-restrain-myself-when-both-playing-a-character-and-dming) as to why DMPC are an insidious evil devised by the Lords of Hell themselves to destroy our hobby.

Comment: +1 for "DMPC are an insidious evil devised by the Lords of Hell themselves to destroy our hobby."